# Parse JSON data into a ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

I know that there are several similar questions already answered, but because the fact that I'm very new to Android development, I couldn't figure out how to solve this on my own. The question is pretty self-explanatory. I'm fetching data from the database over HTTP request and want to adapt that data into a listview. I'm using Volley for my HTTP requests and underneath is my `onResponse` -method.

Everything else works perfectly, I just haven't found a way to adapt that data into a listview.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
    // If we are getting success from server

    try {
      JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
      int count = jObject.getInt("count");

      if(count == 0) {
        noEventsTextView.setText(jObject.getString("msg").toString());
        noEventsTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        noEventsImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      } else {
        JSONArray childArray = jObject.getJSONArray("lectures");

        for(int i = 0; i < childArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject finalObject = childArray.getJSONObject(i);

          // TODO Adapt data to listView
        }
      }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And here's an example of JSON I get back from the server:

```
{
  count: 2,
  msg: "",
lectures: [
  {
    id: "1",
    starting_at: "2015-11-30 13:00:00",
    ending_at: "2015-11-30 15:00:00",
    user_id: "1",
    course: "Course #1",
    user_name: "John Doe"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    starting_at: "2015-11-30 13:00:00",
    ending_at: "2015-11-30 15:00:00",
    user_id: "1",
    course: "Course #2",
    user_name: "John Doe"
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: using key parameter value store all values in list the add to base adapter.

Answer (score 0):

create array Variables for each key value pairs of `Json`. 
and pass all those variable to a `listview`. 
new `Listadapter(this,id[],starting_at[],ending_at[],user_id[],course[],username[]);`

or There is a concept called `Gson`. 
which will allow you to write data to `Serializable` class without using array. 
And after assigning data to these class you can pass the `Serializable` class to adapter and used it inside adapter getView method.

There is a simple [tutorial](http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2015/11/adding-json-array-to-serializable-class.html) on this which I wrote to assign data to serializable class, think it will give you an idea.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of each key value pairs of Json and the map your json to that class using Jackson and the add generic list of that class to your List Adapter .
    Like

```
Custom Class{
    String id;
    String starting_at;
    String ending_at;
    String user_id;
    String course ;
    String username;
}
```

Map your response through Jackson to ArrayList
and then 
    ListAdapter(ArrayList)
    https://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-json-parsing-made-easy-using-jackson/

and you are ready to go.......you can use gson also but jackson is a bit faster so you can go for anyone according to ur need......

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a POJO consisting of all the keys a lecture has.

**DataPOJO.java**

```
public class DataPOJO {
    private int id;
    private String starting_at;
    private String ending_at;
    private String user_id;
    private String course;
    private String user_name;
}
```

Inside your onResponse:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
    // If we are getting success from server

    try {
      JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
      int count = jObject.getInt("count");

      if(count == 0) {
        noEventsTextView.setText(jObject.getString("msg").toString());
        noEventsTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        noEventsImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      } else {
        JSONArray childArray = jObject.getJSONArray("lectures");
        ArrayList<DataPOJO> datas = new ArrayList<DataPOJO>();
        for(int i = 0; i < childArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject finalObject = childArray.getJSONObject(i);
          DataPOJO data = new DataPOJO;
          data.id = finalObject.getInt("id");
          data.starting_at = finalObject.getString("starting_at");

          //so on

          //add data to arraylist......
          datas.add(data);

        }

        //set adapter of your listview here, you have to have an instance of your list view
       listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(datas, context));
      }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<DataPOJO> listItem;

    public MyAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<DataPOJO> listItem) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView =   LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);

             ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(listItem.get(position).user_name);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**list_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot resolve method 'getId()'` in MyAdapter.Java and `Cannot resolve symbol context` in onResponse and wasn't able to test this one out :/ Any ideas ?

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work. Thank you :) One more question though, am I able to create `onClickListenener`s for custom listViews? I need to open a new Intent after clicking each course

Comment: you can use `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` after setting adapter on listview.